# How can i publish artifacts to S3 buckets using jenkinsfile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to publish my success build artifacts to AWS S3 bucket using Jenkinsfile.

Please assist me with this I am a new bee.

From googling I came to know that we have to use S3 publisher plugin for this. but now sure how to write a groovy script.

Regards,
Subramanian L

Answer (score 2):

1. Install a plugin called as Pipeline AWS on Jenkins. Plugins can be installed under "Manage Plugins" section.
2. Under Credentials -> System -> Global credentials add your AWS access key ID and secret access key. Make sure these creds have required S3 permissions.
3. Sample groovy code for pipeline.

```
node {
    stage('Upload') {
        dir('path/to/your/project/workspace'){
            withAWS(region:'your-S3-bucket-region',credentials:'newly-created-credentials-ID') {
                 def identity=awsIdentity();
                // Upload files from working directory to project workspace
                s3Upload(bucket:"use-S3", workingDir:'your-working-dir', includePathPattern:'**/*');
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @udhav Thank you so much for your response, the working directory is /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project-name>/ ... So does this upload entire gitclone to S3?

Comment: @SubramanianLakshmanan Yes as the path pattern is "*". You can be specific to upload single file.

Comment: I have a question: what would be the workigDir under s3Upload. is it /var/lib/jenkins or subfolder of s3 bucket?

Comment: eg 1. Include all files of a specific extention:
`s3Upload(bucket:"my-bucket", path:'path/to/targetFolder/', includePathPattern:'**/*.txt', workingDir:'/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project-name>/<dir-where-files-exist>')`

eg 2. Include all files except specific extention:
`s3Upload(bucket:"my-bucket", path:'path/to/targetFolder/', includePathPattern:'**/*', workingDir:'/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project-name>/<dir-where-files-exist>', excludePathPattern:'**/*.txt')`

3. jenkins plugin docs: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/#s3upload